# In Powershell CSOM for SharePoint 2013 site, how to check if "Variation Lables" list exists or not?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, sharepoint-foundation, powershell

In PowerShell CSOM for SharePoint 2013 site, How to check if 
"Variation Labels" list is exists or not?

Comment: what is variation list? if you setup variations, so where they are saved? have you any screenshot of this list?

Comment: i want script to check for any list whether that exists or not. not specific to "variation labels" list only.

Comment: @ZdeněkVinduška i meant to say "varation Labels" list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following PowerShell with CSOM for your reference.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

$siteURL = "http://sp2013/sites/team"  
$username="admin"
$password="xx"
$domain="contoso"

$creds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password, $domain);
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)  
$ctx.credentials = $creds  
try{  
    $rootWeb = $ctx.Site.RootWeb
    $varLabelsList = $rootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Variation Labels")
    $ctx.Load($varLabelsList)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    write-host "The Variation Labels list exists." -foregroundcolor green 
}  
catch{  
    write-host "The Variation Labels list not exists." -foregroundcolor red
}
```